# Ctrl+D Can it be remapped in FireFox or disabled in Outlook?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook, autohotkey

If I want to bookmark something in FireFox, I use Ctrl+D. If Outlook is the active Window, Ctrl+D will delete the highlighted item. This has happens when I'm jumping back and forth between monitors and not paying attention to which window is active. Then I'm solving the mystery of what I deleted.

**Is there a way to change the Ctrl+D hotkey mapping in FireFox or disable Ctrl+D in Outlook?**

The best option I can think of is to use AutoHotKey to map another key combo to Ctrl+D when FireFox is active. Any better suggestions?

Comment: Although I do like using keyboard shortcuts, I prefer pressing the star icon when I create bookmarks in Firefox.  Besides avoiding the problem that you described, I can also use the `Folder` pull-down menu to create the bookmark in my preferred folder, rather than moving it from `Other Bookmarks` later.

Comment: The star icon is quick, but I like to put my bookmarks in folders. Ctrl+D seems to be quicker for that.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you found a good solution!  That being said, perhaps I am missing something:  utilizing `Ctrl+D` seems to open the same interface as the star icon.  How is the keyboard shortcut faster at placing bookmarks in folders?  As I said in my previous comment, I already do that very quickly with the star icon, and I don't need to rely upon AutoHotkey (or anything else) to intervene.

Comment: Short answer is you're right but I still like my hotkeys. I clicked the star icon this morning and thought I was going crazy. The "Bookmark this Page" dialog came up and let me pick a folder. At one point in time when you would click the Star icon, it would just add it to the unsorted bookmarks. I couldn't find when this change happened, but found reports as resent as 2016. At one point double-clicking the Star would bring up the dialog box. Now single-clicking does the same thing.

Comment: *"Short answer is you're right but I still like my hotkeys."*  And if it's strictly a personal preference, that's fine.  I asked because I could tell that you hadn't tried it, but it actually provides the same capability (and has for quite some time) without the need to depend upon AutoHotkey.  If you are happy with the end result, that's all that counts.  Personally, I prefer to keep my Windows builds as stable and streamlined as possible:  a minimal number of applications, etc.  It seems to work rather well, *and* I have never had a problem with accidentally deleting my e-mail messages.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (AHK script):

```
; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (WinActive("ahk_exe outlook.exe") && WinExist("ahk_exe firefox.exe")) ; "&&" means "and"

    ; Ctrl+D: 
    ^d::
        MsgBox, 4,, Are you sure you want to send Ctrl+D to Outlook`nwhile FireFox exists?
        IfMsgBox Yes
            Send, {Ctrl Down}d{Ctrl Up}
    return

#If  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Use Window Spy to find out the exact **ahk_exe** of the Outlook window (may differ if you have another MS Office suite).

Comment: It worked great! Clever solution. Happy I don't have to change what hotkeys I use. Thanks!