# Map Ctrl+D to no-op in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook desktop application (not office 365 or any cloud/web app counterpart), is there a way to map Ctrl+D to a no-op (no operation)?

At least in Outlook Journal, it is mapped to Delete by default.  This is very dangerous, since Alt+D and Ctrl+S are near-neighbour combinations.  I have found that I deleted many things without awareness in the course of doing things quickly.  I actually can't understand why a shortcut key is needed for Delete.  There is already a single keyboard key for that.

In the course of posting this, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1292859/ctrld-can-it-be-remapped-in-firefox-or-disabled-in-outlook) was suggested.  However, I would like to avoid a 3rd party app (and on some computers, I can't install anything).  Besides, binding a shortcut key to a command isn't so much the problem as is the question of whether there is a no-op command.

I guess I can always define a macro that does nothing, then bind Ctrl+D to it, but that's an extra step on all computers that I use.  It would be better to use a native Outlook command.  A clunky way to do this is to bind Ctrl+D to Save-As, then banish the Save-As window if it gets inadvertently invoked.  But it is clunky compared to an actual no-op.  Also, enabling macros is a security compromise that I would like to avoid if possible, especially if the only reason is to provide no-op functionality.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, we can disable Ctrl+D(delete) in Outlook by changing GPO settings:

1.Locate to: ***User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Outlook 2013\Disable items in user interface\Custom***.
[image]

2.**Double click Disable shortcut keys>click Enable>click Show…>type 68,8** (Values for Ctrl+D)

(If you want to disable other shortcut keys, to find corresponding values, refer to: [Values for shortcut keys and modifiers in Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179143(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#values-for-shortcut-keys-and-modifiers-in-office-2013))

[image]

3.Then restart Outlook, you will find the "Ctrl+D" is not available for Delete.

For the steps of configuring GPO, please refer to @Yuki Sun's answer in this thread: [Disable Outlook 2013 keyboard shortcut](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/300aa269-9006-4905-9793-aa4dfe41847c/disable-outlook-2013-keyboard-shortcut?forum=outlook).

Hope the above help!

Comment: Thanks, Christy, but I don't have the privileges across all the computers that I use.  I think I'm stuck with the lowest denominator -- a command within Outlook itself that can be bound to a shortcut key.  The Save-As command seems to be a candidate, since I can banish the window of Ctrl+D gets pressed.  Not great, I know.

Comment: Well, if so, I have no better suggestion.