# Registry edit to disble Ctrl+D in Outlook Desktop 2019

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, group-policy, microsoft-outlook-2019

I use Outlook Desktop 2019 on Windows 10.  For me, Ctrl+D is hazardous because it deletes an item when I actually meant to type (say) Ctrl+S or Alt+D.  Furthermore, the mapping of Ctrl+D to deletion is completely unnecessary because there is *already* a Delete key.

I a following [this process](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/271) to disable Ctrl+D.  It says to navigate to *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\**version**\Outlook\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes.* Unfortunately, I can only get as far as *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft*.  There is no "Office" subfolder.

I also tried the [this process](https://superuser.com/a/1720409/767015) for editing the Group Policy.  It says to navigate to *User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Microsoft Outlook 20**XX**\Disable items in user interface\Custom.*  Unfortunately, I can only get as far as *User Configuration\Administrative Templates.*  There is no *Microsoft Outlook 20XX subfolder.*  I did launch `gpedit` as administrator.

***Why would the required paths not appear in "regedit" nor "gpedit"?***

This Office installation is legit.

Comment: It looks like you could use AutoHotkey to do nothing when ctrl+D is pressed when Outlook is the active window: [How do I configure hotkeys to be used in only one program](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=19&t=85894) and [Disabling specific keys, such as "alt"](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=98336).

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I was hoping that there would be a native solution.

Comment: Keep hoping - someone might be along in the next day with a better idea.

Comment: Did you try creating the missing structure and keys in Registry? That is often a perfectly valid process. There are many settings that when unconfigured mean there is no registry key or value there, and when you want to add that, you just create the missing bits to complete the path.

Comment: Honestly, I tread in the registry (and even the group policy) with great trepidation.  On rare occassion, I see solutions to problems involving creation of folders at the lower levels (or so I *think*, I can't really recall), but never so far up.  I will mull this over a bit before I take the plunge.